# Data studio - cannot add more than 10 dimensions to a blended data source

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I am trying to make a blended data source from 2 bigquery tables. The problem I am seeing is that I am not able to add more than 10 fields as dimensions in each table for the join.

As you can see in the image below, the `Add dimension` option is not available for the first table. If I remove one of these dimensions, I get the `Add dimension` option back.

[image]

Is there a limitation on the number of dimensions that can be added to the tables of a blended data source?

Answer (score 3):

A solution (that i really don't like but works) is to add all the dimensions to the report attached to the datasource and not to the blend and then pressing "blend data" in the right panel. After this, in the bind creation view will appear the datasource that was attached before with all the dimensions that you added (it can be more than 10), but you will not be able to add more if the quantity of dimensions is greater than 10

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found to this was to Add the same table again to the blended data source and add the remaining fields as dimensions. In my case, it was `purchases` joined with `purchases`.

I am not sure, if this is the right approach. I just want to know if this is a limitation from data studio?

Comment: This is a very crude solution, but will definitely get you forward. When anyone looks at it 6 months down the line, there will be many WTFs flying in the room.

Comment: Agreed!! I have come past this one and it is already 6 months

Answer (score -2):

Google Studio does have limitations as stated in Docs [here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)

> Limits of tables
>
> The number of dimensions and metrics you can add depends on the data
> source used by that table:
>
> 1. Tables based on "fixed schema" data sources, such as Google
>    Analytics, Google Ads, Display & Video 360, and other Google
>    marketing products data sources can have up to 10 dimensions and 20
>    metrics.
> 2. Tables based on "flexible schema" data sources, such as Google
>    Sheets, BigQuery, and SQL databases can have up to 100 dimensions
>    and 100 metrics.

Comment: **NOTE**: While the reference is useful, it does not answer this specific question. The cited reference quotes the limits for a specific chart type ([Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044)) directly from the (unblended) data source, while the question is regarding the field limitations (dimensions and or metrics) during the [blend](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420).

Comment: Also, OP asked about BugQuery, and the docs claims the limit is 100 dimensions. Although effectively it is 10. Same phenomenon for a Google Sheets data source.